# What is the difference between /etc/modules and /etc/modprobe.d/?

Tags: drivers, kernel, raspberrypi

I am trying to load a module (bcm2835-v4l2) when booting my system, however, my research has shown two ways I can get the module loaded.

I can either append the name of the module to the end of the /etc/modules file

or I can add a

- NAMEOFMODULE.conf

file within /etc/modprobe.d/ and add the name of the module

(in my case, '/etc/modprobe/bcm2835-v4l2.conf').

Two questions:

1. What is the difference between these two? 
   I have already seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189670/whats-the-difference-of-etc-modules-load-d-and-etc-modules?newreg=98247670cab9407085cf5c26fea4fb71) in unix.stackexchange, so anything that is more extensive or more clear is preferred
2. Which should I prefer in this situation, and in general? Or is it not worth having a preference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that there is a definitive, documented answer in Ubuntu. I am happy to learn otherwise.

What is most often and traditionally used is that if you simply want the module to load at boot automatically with no human intervention, use `/etc/modules`.

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

bcm2835-v4l2
```

If you'd like to load the module with some available parameters listed in `modinfo`, write a .conf file `/etc/modprobe.d/bcm2835-v4l2.conf`:

```
options bcm2835-v4l2 some_parameter=Y
```

Note that this is an example only. I am not certain that bcm2835-v4l2 has or even needs any manipulable parameters.